# Custom Logging Interface for PRISM Bootstrapper

Tags: c#, prism, nlog

I am currently developing a PRISM based WPF application. I am currently wondering if it is possible to make PRISM use my own LoggingInterface.

I would like to do the following:

```
public class MyBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
     [...]
     /// <summary>
    /// Creates the logger.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns a <see cref="IMyLoggerFacade"/> implementation.</returns>
    protected override IMyLoggerFacade CreateLogger()
    {
        return new MyLoggerFacade();
    }
}
```

Instead of having to use the ILoggerFacade of PRISM.

Can you guys help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The reason for this is more like "I don't like it".
I am more comfortable with an interface like Logger.Debug(), Logger.Info and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifications to [ILoggerFacade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.logging.iloggerfacade%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) would require you to edit the Prism source code, rebuild the binaries, and reference these in your project.

However, you can create extension methods for `ILoggerFacade`, such as

```
public static class LoggerFacadeExtensions
{
    public static void Debug(this ILoggerFacade logger, string message)
    {
        logger.Log(message, Category.Debug, Priority.High);
    }
}
```

Then

```
logger.Debug("Your debug message");
```

Comment: This is what I have done so far but it also feels a little dirty ... 
I guess I'll just stick with the ILoggerFacade interface ...